# Meteor DDP context

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'm creating package for distributed ddp clients

Basic routine is as follow:

1. Client connect
2. if it's new it negotiate its own key and secret with Diffie–Hellman key exchange algorithm
3. then logs in with key and encrypted password

Users can assign clients to their accounts by searching with given ip

This way we have automatic client registration.

What I want to solve is to design functionality similar to Meteor.userId on server side

step1:
ddp client logs in, (skip DH algorithm)

```
//client:
DDPClient.call('register',[key:key,token:token, ip:ip]);

//server
Meteor.methods({
  'register' : function(options){
    var self = this;
    // check key token

    // store registered clientId similar to Meteor.userId in currentContext
    // self contains field _sessionData;
    // storing data inside this method works fine 
    _.extend(self._sessionData, {clientId: ID }
  }
});
```

step2:
ddp client calls other methods

```
//client:
DDPClient.call('other-method',[]);

//server
Meteor.methods({
  'other-method' : function(options){
    var self = this;
    //this returns what we set inside register method
    console.log(self._sessionData.clientId);
  }
});
```

Problem is with Meteor.publish methods is there some easy way to restart all subscriptions in current context with valid ClientID ? I can follow setUserId method from livedata package but it uses a lot internals I would like not to touch

this have to work

```
Meteor.publish('data' : function(){
  var self = this;

  var clientId = ?????

  return Data.find({owner : clientId});
});
```

Or there is some other way to accomplish my task?
I simply want to keep client id in the context so it don't have to authorize on each method call

this solution is not acceptable

```
Meteor.publish('data', function(clientId){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.userId()` exists server-side already, in any location other than a publish function. If you're within a publish function, you can use `this.userId` instead.